# Php Chat implementation

Tags: php, html, ajax

Hai

I want to build a web site containing chat. i am working with PHP,  I want  a code to implement a chat with php .Any one help me to do this?  I know Ajax . i don't Know any other languages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are currently working with LiveZilla, this very well, the only thing the company must have Windows PC. The operator interface is on ".NET"

[livezilla](http://www.livezilla.net/)

Comment: As far as I can see this is shameless advertising.

Comment: you have no idea what he is saying. I speak from my experience as a user, I'm from Argentina and I have no relationship with LiveZilla. 
With comments like yours are denied freedom of experción on opensouce projects.

Comment: Don't get all "freedom of experción" just because he uses his freedom of expression by leaving a comment. It comes with all these freedoms that others also speak their mind.

Comment: Ok, but this is not a shameless advertisement. is disrespectful to think that.

Comment: Not at all, it's because it's worded as self-promotion (and not very well worded) that it sounds like advertising.

Comment: 1 - This response was 2009. 2 - I'm from Argentina and I have no connection with the product. 3 - is a free product. I don't find the sense of your comment after 3 years.

Answer (score 3):

> Ajax Chat is a light-weight
>   customizable web chat software
>   implemented in JavaScript and PHP. The
>   script does not require Java, Flash,
>   or any other plugins. Features:
>
> - Public and private chat.
> - Login as a registered user or as a guest.
> - Away status, custom colors, smileys, user gender/status icons.
> - Ajax Chat can be integrated with a third-party membership system by
>     implementing user authentication
>     routine. Advanced integration options:
>     if user is logged in to the website,
>     he can be logged in to the chat
>     automatically.

http://www.php-development.ru/javascripts/ajax-chat.php

Also you can read this

[Writing a JavaScript/PHP Chat Server](http://code.jenseng.com/jenChat/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a ready solution instead of reinventing the wheel. Try [phpFreeChat](http://www.phpfreechat.net/).

Comment: But Testadmin didn't want to reinvent the wheel -- he wanted someone else to do it for him, thus demonstrating one of the characteristics of a great programmer.