# Finding a better way to create a chat app

Tags: php, ajax

I have created a chat app using JavaScript that works only in IE, so now I have decided to create a chat app in php so that it works in every browser but I am unable to figure out where to begin.

I created a text file (I'm trying to make it as xml soon) and I can write to the text file.

Some sample scripts:

```
<html file>
<form method="post" action="chat.php">
    <input type="text" name="message" 'some styling done'>
</form>
<php file>
<?php
 $mesage = $_POST['message']
 create file for first time then append the message variable value
?>
```

This method opens a chat.php page from the html page.  I found a solution something like these on google by making `action=""` and using like `$isset` but sorry I lost that website so I could not fix it and the other solution I thought was using frames.

But I heard frames may fade off in time and finally I read that AJAX can do the magic but I'm not much aware of ajax.  I read some tutorials but still unable to understand it, I just want to know how to write to a xml or txt file from AJAX and also how to read from a file.

I'm a beginner in php and my first project is chat app so kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this similar to the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310265/php-chat-implementation

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following example which is the most minimal ajax, php/js example I can find: http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/simple-plain-ajax-without-any-javascript-library/

I would recommend using that code as an example of how to get what you want working. Make sure you get it working before editing it. Ajax can seem an overwhelming topic at first, but if you hang in there you will get it. You could also try to get a simple form posting to your php page so that pressing a button will send content to your php from your front end. That could be an easier learning step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an already existing solution as the other answers sugest if this is time and quality important, but I think as a beginner you could use the practice of writing one.

Whatever you decide, my suggestion would be to use and already existing protocol. You could even use an existing server and focus on the client for the first part so you don't get bombarded with too many things at one time. This will maximize the chance that you will get something done. Once you're done with that, if you want the exercise, you can take the server part too.

XMPP is in my opinion the best thing out there and there are [many open source libraries](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20xmpp) for all sorts of languages. There are even [open source servers](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) and [free services](http://xmpp.org/resources/public-services/) that you can use.