# How to pass AJAX information to another user from user with button click in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to implement AJAX to refresh the content automatically when there is new notification is incoming for the user.

---

Example for what I am trying to achieve:

`user A` sent a friend request to `user B`, so `user B` gets a notification, but the notification is only showing after the page is refreshed. I want to refresh the notification automatically, whenever the database is updated/inserted a new value.

AJAX:

```
$('#ajax').click(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  '../main/count-fnd.php',
    success: function(data){
        $('#output').html(data);
    }
 });
});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php Chat implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310265/php-chat-implementation)

Comment: There are several techniques you could use. The first one is not synchronous. So, what you could do, is to make an AJAX request every X seconds, to make sure that the user has a friend request. Unfortunately, this solution is not the best, as it could consume a lot of resources in the server side. Imagine, your network has 10000 members, and all are connected at the same time. That means that all 10000 members will make a request to the server to check for friend requests. Another solution, that is more lightweight, is the use of web sockets where all members are getting updated simultaneously

Comment: For more information you could see the following links: http://socketo.me/ & https://socket.io/

Comment: @Sam, it is clearly not duplicate question. I am not trying to do a chat application.

Comment: @Chris_00 it's exactly like that, replace 'notification' with 'chat message'

Comment: @Sam, lol, clearly not the same, again, and that doesn't solved my problem...

Comment: @Chris_00 ok, as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with AJAX (without using other technologies), the most used, rather the typical in these cases, is to use some kind of timer to refresh and check if there is any new notification every "x" seconds that you stipulate.

```
setInterval(() => {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url:  '../main/count-fnd.php',
       success: function(data){
           $('#output').html(data);
       }
    });
}, 5000); // refresh 5s
```

Comment: That is hopefully not the typical case, why send a request to your server every 5 seconds that, worst case, doesn't return anything? I'd rather go with server push/pubsub/websockets

Comment: You have not understood my answer well and you have hastened to vote it negative. CLEARLY, the CORRECT thing is to use websockets. But if you want to do it only by AJAX without having other technology or sockets, this is the typical case.

Comment: In fact the question says: "How to pass AJAX information to another user from user with button click in php?" not "What is the best way to ..."

Comment: @JoseFG what is the best way to do it?

Comment: fyi, I didn't DV your answer

Comment: @Chris_00 how well they commit you, using some kind of technology that listens and can launch an event when the desired data is modified. Perhaps the best example as you are told is the use of sockets.